# Is there a programmatic interface to Excel's Array Formulae?

Tags: excel, vba, array-formulas

For example, suppose I have

```
{={1,2,3,4,5}}
```

in a cell. Is there any way to find out how many elements are in that array, and what those elements are?

Now implementing @chris neilsen's idea, I've now got a VBA function as below

```
Function rinfo(r As Range) As String
    With r.CurrentArray
        rinfo = .Address & ", " & .Rows.Count & ", " & .Columns.Count & ", " & .Value & ", " & .Value2
    End With
End Function
```

however the data from it doesn't look to hopeful, viz

```
$A$29, 1, 1, 1, 1
```

The Rows.Count and Columns.Count make sense if they are counting the rows and cols used in the worksheet. But as an indication of the data in the array formula, no.

Comment: From where ? VBA, or another formula ?

Comment: @chris neilsen's solution works fine. For your `{={1,2,3,4,5}}
` example, if you do indeed have a 1x5 array, then the `.Value` and `.Value2` methods should be throwing a type mismatch error because they don't apply to arrays... But they don't, which makes me think that your array is of size 1x1 on your sheet.

Comment: @Jean  when called from a udf for some reason `.CurrentArray` does not return the whole range, but just the first cell, hence no error in the example.  That why I said "In a Sub".  Even more oddly if the Function is called from a Sub it *does* return an array and the example *will* error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your formula only occupies a single cell, and a cell can only contain a scalar value, so after the cell has been calculated it will contain 1.
 But you can evaluate the formula from VBA and that can give you an array result. If your formula is in A1 then

```
Dim vArr As Variant
vArr = Evaluate(Range("a1").Formula)
```

will result in vArr containing an array of of 4 variants of the 4 numbers.
 There are several "quirks" to the Evaluate method: see [one of my web pages](http://www.decisionmodels.com/calcsecretsh.htm) for details.

Comment: Aha, now I understand the question. +1

Answer (score 1):

In a `Sub`, if `cl` is a `Range` and is set to a cell that is part of an array formula, then

```
cl.CurrentArray
```

returns the range that contains the array formula.

If your example formula was in cells `A1:E1` and the activecell is any of cells A1 .. E1, then running

```
Sub zx()
    MsgBox "ref = " & ActiveCell.CurrentArray.Address
End Sub
```

would return a message of `ref = $A$1:$E$1`

You can use `.Rows.Count` and `.Columns.Count` to get the size, and `.Value` to get the values